# Set width of y-axis labels in CanvasJS?

Tags: canvasjs

I'm looking for a way to set the width of the labels along the Y axis using CanvasJS. I can set the max-width, but that's not what I want. I'd like to be able to simply set the width to eg. 200px, and just have extra space to the left or right of the label if it happens to be shorter.

A little background: we're showing 3 separate column charts vertically on a page & need the Y axes to line up. The width of the labels for each of the 3 charts varies though.

Current results (bad, Y axes not lined up)

```
1,500 |
1,000 |   [chart 1]
500   |
0     ----------------- 

0.4 |
0.3 |   [chart 2]
0.2 |
0.1 |
0   ----------------- 

$40,000 |
$30,000 |   [chart 3]
$20,000 |
$10,000 |
$0      -----------------
```

Desired results (good, Y axes lined up)

```
1,500   |
1,000   |   [chart 1]
500     |
0       ----------------- 

0.4     |
0.3     |   [chart 2]
0.2     |
0.1     |
0       ----------------- 

$40,000 |
$30,000 |   [chart 3]
$20,000 |
$10,000 |
$0      -----------------
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can achieve that. But you can use margin and align all the charts. However, the labels won't start from the left position. Instead, it'd create a gap before the label starts.

```
axisY: [{
    labelMaxWidth: 100,
    prefix: "This"
}]
```

You'd have to set the value of margin to align it. To do so, you can use set method.

```
chart2.axisY[0].set("margin", chart.axisY[0].bounds.x2 - (chart2.axisY[0].bounds.x2 - chart2.axisY[0].bounds.x1));
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvwc4zmb/1/). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Beevk. I received a very similar response from CanvasJS support & used it to find the highest x2 value & set the margin of the other charts accordingly. It worked like a charm. As you said, the labels are right-justified with a gap on the left when there is extra space, but it looks great. Thanks again!